# How to get variable variable with array value

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

How I can use variable variables with array to get result like is below?

I've tried so far:

```
// $g_module_id_bar_1['id'] = 5;

$i = 1;

$variablename = 'g_module_id_bar_'.$i;
$key = '\'id\'';

echo $$variablename[$key];
```

Result should be: **5**

Comment: It's better to be `$g_module_id_bars[1]['id'] = 5;`

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The changes made to [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) in PHP 7 will have an effect on how the last line is processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it.

Change `$key = '\'id\'';` too `$key='id';`

The reason is because PHP understands that `$key` contains a string. When accessing an array noramlly, you wouldn't do something like:

```
 <?php     
 $var = array("hello"=>"world");   
 echo $var["'hello'"];
```

which is effectively what you were doing

See for full solution:
https://3v4l.org/qk5ZL

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake. Thanks for help.

Comment: @AdamMakowski =) np

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to escape single quotes but this is useless, just use the string key:

```
$key = 'id';
echo $$variablename[$key]; // 5
```